# BLOB type in my sql

Tags: mysql, blob

I have stored a **.swf** file's path in a table say **Test**,

I have made the table feild type in as BLOB. Now the problem ,while retriving in dosen't render as an swf file.

Is BLOB datatype in mysql is not for storing file types like .swf?

How can i fix my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you storing only file path? or file itself?

Comment: BLOB is fine for storing .swf file. What do you mean be its not rendered correctly?

Comment: @Anshu it is displaying only as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to save just a path of file or file?
If you need to save just a path of file you can use vachar or text field.

Answer (score 0):

BLOB is storing for BINARY types. But you said that you stored .swf's path in that field. You should put the contents of swf into that field typed as BLOB. Or change field type to varchar and just store the path in it.